# Реализовать d-ary heap

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть две функции, которые поддерживают порядок в бинарном сортирующем дереве. Помогите разобраться, как изменить их так, чтобы можно было перестраивать пирамиду произвольной арности.

Работу исходных функций я более-менее понимаю. Функция fixUp принимает на входе номер элемента, который мы добавляем в пирамиду, проверяет, не превосходит ли он своих родителей, и если это так, то меняет его местами со своим родителем (поднимает вверх по дереву). Уже здесь есть пара вопросов:
1. Почему в условии цикла node > 1 и по какому индексу находится корень дерева? Думаю, такое условие связано с расположением корня. В С++ индексы начинаются с нуля, но здесь я не вижу, чтобы использовался этот факт.
2. Почему индекс родителя рассчитывается как i/2, а не (i - 1)/2?

Далее, работаем с произвольной арностью, равной d. Обычно индекс родителя рассчитывается как (i - 1)/d. В каких случаях он рассчитывается так, а в каких i/d?

В функции fixDown я не понимаю смысла условия цикла 2*node <= n. Почему оно именно такое, и что такое 2? Что дальше происходит в цикле?

И еще: что возвращать в функции getmax(), если не выполняется условие !empty()?

```
#include <iostream>

#define d 3 /*Арность кучи*/

/*Реализация функций перестроения бинарной кучи*/
template <class Item>
void fixUp(Item a[], int node){
    while(node > 1 && a[node/2] < a[node]){
    std::swap(a[node], a[node/2]);
    node = node / 2;
    }
}

template <class Item>
void fixDown(Item a[], int node, int n){
    while(2*node <= n){
        int j = 2*node;

        if(j < n && a[j] < a[j + 1]) j++;
        if(!(a[node] < a[j])) break;
        std::swap(a[node], a[j]);
        node = j;
    }
}

/*Реализация функций перестроения d-арной кучи*/
template <class Item>
void d_ary_fixUp(Item a[], int node){
    while(node > 1 && a[(node - 1)/d] < a[node]){
        std::swap(a[node], a[(node - 1)/d]);
        node = (node - 1) / d;
    }
}

template <class Item>
void d_ary_fixDown(Item a[], int node, int n){
    while(d*node <= n){
        int j = d*node;

        if(j < n && a[j] < a[j + 1]) j++;
        if(!(a[node] < a[j])) break;
        std::swap(a[node], a[j]);
        node = j;
    }
}

template <class Item>
class PQ{
private:
    Item *pq;
    int n;
public:
    PQ(int max){
        pq = new Item[max + 1];
        n = 0;
    }

    ~PQ(){
        delete[] pq;
    }

    int empty() const{
        return n == 0;
    }

    void insert(Item item){
        pq[++n] = item;
        d_ary_fixUp(pq, n);
    }

    Item getmax(){
        if(!empty()){
            std::swap(pq[1], pq[n]);
            d_ary_fixDown(pq, 1, n-1);
            return pq[n--];
        }else
            return 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    PQ<int> pq(50);
    int p;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pq.insert(i);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        std::cout << pq.getmax() << " ";
    std::cin >> p;
}
```

Надеюсь, код отформатировался как надо.
Результат выполнения кода: https://ideone.com/PgFn3V